# Listing All Tables and Columns from my Database (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to know how it is possible to list all the tables and columns from my ORACLE database **but by "grouping" all this information into only one table**? A table with two columns: one with the name of the table and the other one with all the colums in that table. Thank you.

***For instance:***

TABLE_NAME COLUMNS

TABLE A => LIST OF COLUMNS

TABLE B => LIST OF COLUMNS

TABLE C => LIST OF COLUMNS

**This is how I list all the tables from my ORACLE database:**

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES;
```

**This is how I list all the columns from one of the tables from my ORACLE database:**

```
SELECT column_name
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: what's wrong with `user_tab_cols`. you found the 2 columns `table_name`and `column_name` already. so what are you missing?

Comment: @Ariana: Aツ is right. But if you want to know other info present only in user_tab_cols you can JOIN two tables using table_name field

Comment: I updated my post. What I want is "grouping" the information of the two selects into one table.

Comment: Join the tables and order the results by table_name.  If you really need a single row for each table, use something more suitable to re-arrange the results.  For example, I could do it in 5 minutes using ColdFusion.

Comment: looks like your question is not your question. `string aggregate oracle`is what you should search with your favourite tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `listagg` to get all the column names in a table as a list.

```
create table table_column_list as 
SELECT table_name,listagg(column_name,',') within group(order by column_id) column_list
FROM user_tab_cols
group by table_name;
```

Comment: Meanwhile, this is exactly the select I made up. Thanks anyway :)